# NIAttributedLabel settextcolor not working

Tags: iphone, ios, nimbus-ios

I am using `NIAttributedLabel` for displaying links on text.

```
            NIAttributedLabel *label;
            label = [[NIAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

            label.delegate = self;
            label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:MAIN_FONT_SIZE];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            label.numberOfLines = 0;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  
            label.text = strEditedText;
            label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            [label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor] 
                          range:[strEditedText rangeOfString:stringPh]];
```

But last line is not working correctly although **stringPh** is in **strEditedText**. All the text is coming in blue.

Comment: What are the values of stringPH and strEditedText?

Comment: **strEditedText** is :  Please contact abc at 800.493.0016, option #3 for further assistance. And **stringPh** is 800.493.0016

Comment: Can you please `NSLog` each of your strings just before the last line? The only thing that may cause this (all text in blue) is when the two strings are the same (hence a range from start to end). I have copy-pasted your code using static strings with the values you provided and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up an example which you can download [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/NIAttributedLabelTest.zip), and I found that it worked perfectly.
With:

```
NSString * strEditedText= @"I'm text";
NSString *stringPh = @"I'm";
```

the simulator correctly highlights the right portion of the text:
[image]

Are you absolutely sure your string `stringPh` is an actual substring of `strEditedText`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Working code for me

```
NSString * strEditedText= @"Please contact abc at 800.493.0016, option #3 for further assistance.";
NSString *stringPh = @"800.493.0016";
NIAttributedLabel *label;
label = [[NIAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];

label.delegate = self;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:MAIN_FONT_SIZE];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  
label.text = strEditedText;
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor] 
              range:[strEditedText rangeOfString:stringPh]];  
[self.view addSubview:label];
```